# Recursive for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

```
def product(n,p=2):
    productList = []
    for k in range(10**(n-1),10**n):
        for kk in range(10**(n-1),10**n):
            productList.append([k,kk,k*kk])
    return productList
```

This function is supposed to return the list which contains the product of 2 n-digit numbers.
How do I make a function that returns the products of p n-digit numbers?
So if p = 4, it should return the products of 4 n-digit numbers.

I think you need nested for loops for these kind of stuff, but I am not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: did you mean `productList.append(...)` in the 5th line?

Comment: @micsthepick, yep thank you for correcting me.

Comment: You are very quickly going to approach list sizes that are probably a bit unwieldy. Would using numpy be acceptable?

Comment: @Billylegota, numpy would work as long as it just doesn't give me the answer and I understand how it works.

Comment: Just to consider the options, what if instead of storing all the numbers you could ever possibly multiply, you just used the multiplication operator to compute them as needed? Or maybe populate a set, if you just need to test if something is a candidate solution?

Comment: @KennyOstrom, that would also work. I am just storing all the number that could be multiplied is simply because I want to know what number * what other number gives me the product.

Comment: So you are generating a lookup table for the factors of each given product?

Comment: I might consider finding the prime factorization and work back from there, if your current approach starts to generate out of memory errors. If it's just to solve some word/number puzzles, then brute force is okay, but they are more fun to do by hand.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are trying to achieve can be done with recursion:

```
def recursive(n, p=2, prev=[]):
    productList = []
    for k in range(10**(n-1),10**n):
        if p == 1:
            productList.append([k, k])
        else:
            for product in recursive(n, p=p-1):
                productList.append([k] + product[:-1] + [k*product[-1]])
    return productList
```

do you need all products to be unique, as this will give (2*4=8) also as (4*2=8)?

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The batteries for this in SymPy are already included:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import subsets
from sympy.core.mul import prod
numbers = [1, 2, 3]  # or whatever factors you want
p = 2  # how many factors you want
for n in subsets(numbers, p, repetition=True):
    print(n + (prod(n),))
```

This outputs

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 3, 3)
(2, 2, 4)
(2, 3, 6)
(3, 3, 9)
```

This is different from cartes (or product) in that you won't get permutations of the factors, e.g. the latter would also give (2, 1, 2), a permutation of (1, 2, 2). You can read more about subsets using `help(subsets)` in SymPy and you can read the source if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

The `itertools.permutations` method is perfect for what you are trying to achieve.

First generate a list of numbers/digits that can be used.

```
digits = list(range(10 ** (n - 1), 10 ** n))
```

Then multiply that list by `p` in order to get `p` copies of each number.

```
digits *= p
```

Finally, use itertools to generate a list of all the permutations (or combinations) possible with a length of `p`.

```
for values in itertools.permutations(digits, p):
    output.append([values, np.prod(values)])
```

The finished function is shown below:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def product(n, p=2):
    output = []

    # Generate a list containing every possible digit.
    digits = list(range(10 ** (n - 1), 10 ** n))

    # Multiply the list by <p> so that we have <p> copies of each digit.
    digits *= p

    # Iterate over each possible permutation of the digits.
    for values in itertools.permutations(digits, p):
        output.append([values, np.prod(values)])

    return output
```

Alternatively, using numpy and sympy you can make the function much faster (albeit at the cost of having the output be an array rather than list).
Here is the code for a numpy + sympy implementation that is faster (citation needed).

```
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations as perm

def product2(n, p=2):
    digits = np.arange(10 ** (n - 1), 10 ** n)
    digits = np.repeat(digits, p)

    permutations = list(perm(digits, size=p))
    output = np.zeros((len(permutations), n + 1))

    for i in range(len(permutations)):
        for j in range(n):
            output[i][j] = permutations[i][j]
        output[i][-1] = np.prod(permutations[i])

    return output
```